# Try to integrate LinkedIn in iPhone application

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, sdk, linkedin-api

I have download the source from https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone . Demo working fine, and try to use in my application.

I have followed all the steps already whatever required as mention here in [post](http://developer.linkedin.com/message/6139#6350) ...

But I have getting the error

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RDLinkedInEngine", referenced from:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RDLinkedInAuthorizationController", referenced from:
```

[image]

When I comment the lines of RDLinkedInEngine and RDLinkedInAuthorizationController then error are removed

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
//    rdEngine = [[RDLinkedInEngine engineWithConsumerKey:kOAuthConsumerKey consumerSecret:kOAuthConsumerSecret delegate:self] retain];
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
//    if( !rdHasAppeared ) {
//        UIViewController* controller = [RDLinkedInAuthorizationController authorizationControllerWithEngine:rdEngine delegate:self];
//        if( controller ) {
//            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
//            rdHasAppeared = YES;
//        }
//        else {
//            NSLog(@"Already authenticated");
//        }
//    }
}
```

I my application I have already integrated MGTwitterEngine from source https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone  Which is wokring ok.

**Amit Battan**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most probably you need to add some static library (.a file)... or src folder itself from linkedIn source...

Comment: I missed the point ...`4- select   "LinkedInClientLibrary.xcodeproj" that you dropped in the right side marke checkbox " LinkedInClientLibrary.a"`.... that error goes ok.. but new error comes 'Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1'

Comment: you need to right click on the error and select open these latest result as transcript text file and see what causing that error.... post it here as well

Comment: you have added 2 file in which size_t EstimateBas64EncodedDataSize(size_t inDataSize) function is define... need to remove one....

Comment: may be you have added same file... one from LinkedIn source and one from twitter or any other external source

Comment: yes may be that... because both using oAuth.. my test application in which I am only using linkedin is working fine..... so any solution for it mehta ji  by I use both in same...

Comment: a lot of confusion here.... when I again starting step by step adding linkedin files then it give me 73 errors...http://developer.linkedin.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/8628-1663/1.png http://developer.linkedin.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/8628-1662/2.png http://developer.linkedin.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/8628-1661/3.png

Comment: you missed to add header path in your project... Or you missed to add some framwork in your project...

Comment: I am not sure what I am missing.... but surely missing something ...bcoz now am even not able rum a new test app which has no MGTwitterEngine.... http://db.tt/Zlxu72t ... http://db.tt/fCv1MkL ... http://db.tt/BHWciQD

Comment: you need to figure this out yourself... some header paths are missing that is for sure... try from square1

Comment: @mihir Thanks.. the lot of error issue solved and only one same error left `Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
` ... and it works fine with out MGTwitterEngine

Comment: my folder name in which project has space ... due this these lot of errors occurs...

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the same issue. It can be solved by setting Library Dependency. Select project target and then select general. There you will find Direct dependencies. Add LinkedInLibrary from LinkedInClientLibrary.xcodeProject

Answer (score 0):

@mihir

```
Build butterfli of project butterfli with configuration Debug

CompileC build/butterfli.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/butterfli.build/Objects-normal/i386/butterfliViewController.o /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/Classes/butterfliViewController.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
cd /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk -fexceptions -fvisibility=hidden -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40100 -iquote /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/build/butterfli.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/butterfli.build/butterfli-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/build/butterfli.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/butterfli.build/butterfli-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/build/butterfli.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/butterfli.build/butterfli-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/build/butterfli.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/butterfli.build/butterfli-project-headers.hmap -F/Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -iquote/Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/LinkedInClientLibrary -I/Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/OAuthConsumeriPhoneLib -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -I/Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/build/butterfli.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/butterfli.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/build/butterfli.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/butterfli.build/DerivedSources -include /var/folders/RE/RE2wCP+eEqaZg4J2Og3nmE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/butterfli_Prefix-aeetprdcvcynktfkafjmijthtlhp/butterfli_Prefix.pch -c /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/Classes/butterfliViewController.m -o /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/build/butterfli.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/butterfli.build/Objects-normal/i386/butterfliViewController.o

/Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/Classes/butterfliViewController.m:321: warning: property 'fbPermissions' requires method '-fbPermissions' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation

Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/butterfli.app/butterfli normal i386
cd /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk -L/Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/build/Debug-iphonesimulator "-L/Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries & Headers" -F/Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/build/butterfli.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/butterfli.build/Objects-normal/i386/butterfli.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -all_load -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -lOAuth -lxml2 /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/LinkedInClientLibrary/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libLinkedInClientLibrary.a -o /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/butterfli.app/butterfli

ld: duplicate symbol _EstimateBas64EncodedDataSize in /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/LinkedInClientLibrary/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libLinkedInClientLibrary.a(Base64Transcoder.o) and /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/butterfli/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries & Headers/libOAuth.a(Base64Transcoder.o)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: you have added 2 file in which size_t EstimateBas64EncodedDataSize(size_t inDataSize) function is define... need to remove one....