# IPhone + Twitter + LinkedIn + Facebook Error : Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Tags: oauth, iphone-sdk-3.0, linkedin-api, facebook-ios-sdk, mgtwitterengine

I am using MGTwitterEngine oAuth and LinkedIn iOS SDK in my iOS application with facebook-ios-sdk

TwitterEngine : https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

LinkedInIphone : https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone

Both integrated well separately, But when I have used both in application then error coming

- FB + Twitter = working well
- FB + LinkedIn = Working Well
- FB + Twitter + LinkedIn = Not Working and giving error:

> Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Please help me where I am wrong.

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256348/try-to-integrate-linkedin-in-iphone-application)

**EDIT**

***Error Transcript Text File***

```
Build butterfli of project butterfli with configuration Debug

Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/butterfli.app/butterfli normal i386
cd /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/Settinglinkedin/10_mar_butterfli
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk -L/Users/pratgupta/Desktop/Settinglinkedin/10_mar_butterfli/build/Debug-iphonesimulator "-L/Users/pratgupta/Desktop/Settinglinkedin/10_mar_butterfli/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries & Headers" -F/Users/pratgupta/Desktop/Settinglinkedin/10_mar_butterfli/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/Settinglinkedin/10_mar_butterfli/build/butterfli.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/butterfli.build/Objects-normal/i386/butterfli.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -all_load -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -lOAuth -lxml2 /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/Settinglinkedin/10_mar_butterfli/LinkedInClientLibrary/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libLinkedInClientLibrary.a -o /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/Settinglinkedin/10_mar_butterfli/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/butterfli.app/butterfli

ld: duplicate symbol _EstimateBas64EncodedDataSize in /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/Settinglinkedin/10_mar_butterfli/LinkedInClientLibrary/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libLinkedInClientLibrary.a(Base64Transcoder.o) and /Users/pratgupta/Desktop/Settinglinkedin/10_mar_butterfli/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries & Headers/libOAuth.a(Base64Transcoder.o)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Amit Battan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@amit as i have already said EstimateBas64EncodedDataSize this function is define in 2 source file... 1 definition source file is coming from LinkedIn source and 1 definition is coming from file which is source of twitter... you need to search **EstimateBas64EncodedDataSize** in your project and remove that one out of two particular package in which these function is defined and most probably it is Base64Encoding related files which are added twice in your project makes compiler confuse on which definition to use for that particular function...

Comment: @mihir according to Transcript text file .. Base64Transcoder.o is in libLinkedInClientLibrary.a and libOAuth.a.. how I remove from it... I tried to remove the 4 files from MGTwitterEngine (NSData+64.h/m, NSString+UUID.h/m), but it not help

Comment: This is a little tricky problem... you need to rebuild the libLinkedInClientLibrary.a library... with libOAuth.a added in that project and those files which contains the EstimateBas64EncodedDataSize function removed from the linkedIn source... are you getting my point... ?

Comment: yes I understand the problem a little bit ... but I don't know how we rebuild libLinkedInClientLibrary.a ...... Is it possible to use directly the files in stead of libLinkedInClientLibrary.a as like twitter files

Comment: yes it is possible... it is also possible to rebuild the library... just download the source code and use in the target there should be option of libLinkedInClientLibrary.a remove those base 64 files... add libOAuth.a in the project and build the libLinkedInClientLibrary.a again... and yes it is possible to use source file directly... without using libLinkedInClientLibrary.a

Comment: as we have 2 folder for linkedin sdk LinkedInClientLibrary and OAuthConsumeriPhoneLib …. and Base64Transcoder.h is imported into OAuthConsumeriPhoneLib/OAuthConsumer/OAHMAC_SHAISignature.m

Comment: LinkedInClientLibrary.xcodeproj has include libOAuthCunsumer_iPhone.a .. and twitter source which I am using has libOAuth.a … should I drop libOAuthCunsumer_iPhone.a

Comment: let me try with only files without compiled library

Comment: I added the [files](http://db.tt/aQ5AzeA) in project  and getting [45 error](http://db.tt/fPX48Aw), when I change the `#import <OAuthConsumer/OAuthConsumer.h>` to `#import "OAuthConsumer.h"` then it gives [69 error](http://db.tt/TVRRuHL) .. I am not getting why in this case it give like `OAuthConsumer.h:27:34: error: OAuthConsumer/OAToken.h: No such file or directory' as it is ok in case of twitter only

Comment: It is hard now to tell the solution without looking into your code... the base line is that you need to remove one copy of code in which same functions are define twice....

Comment: I try to change the HEADER SEARCH PATH to $(SRCROOT)/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries_Headers ... but it still giving same error ... can it works?

Comment: as far as there are two definition of any function or global variables.... It can not work... header is just for declaration... definition resides in source file

Comment: so confusing man.. thanks.. lets see how much time it will take to solve... and let you ..

Comment: o sorry forgot the paste https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone/blob/master/OAuthConsumeriPhoneLib/ReadMe.txt

Comment: Thanks Mihir! This is right on. FYI: Same problem happens when using ShareKit. In that case, it's a bit easier: Just remove the crypto from one or the other (same files), and you're good to go. By that I mean remove from the _target_. I'd leave the files in place, but that's me. :)

Comment: I done one thing that is ... I remove the library files of linkedin sdk.. and add the source files of it with oAuth files from twiiter sdk... then it works ok for linkedin http://i.imgur.com/cXLXU.png http://i.imgur.com/ntV9G.png ....then I integrate all twitter code then project run ok without error but for twitter login interface it shows PAGE NOT FOUND ..http://i.imgur.com/8a1ua.png

Comment: solved now...I have given the same key and secret to both linkedin and twitter ..after changing them it works

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue is that both our LinkedIn library and Ben Gottlieb's Twitter client include the same OAuthConsumer code. In fact (as the README says) the code in [LinkedIn-iPhone](https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone) was literally copied from his project, with his changes.

That being the case, it should be possible to get this to work by removing our copy of the code (the entire `OAuthConsumeriPhoneLib` folder). You may also need to either change the `#import` lines in our sources, or your project's header search paths, to get our code to find the OAuthConsumer headers from his copy of the code.

(I acknowledge that this is a pain. But we wanted to be sure that our code would build out of the box, without needing to install other stuff.)

Comment: I done one thing that is ... I remove the library files of linkedin sdk.. and add the source files of it with oAuth files from twiiter sdk... then it works ok for linkedin http://i.imgur.com/cXLXU.png http://i.imgur.com/ntV9G.png ....then I integrate all twitter code then project run ok without error but for twitter login interface it shows PAGE NOT FOUND ..http://i.imgur.com/8a1ua.png

Answer (score 0):

'duplicate symbol' means one of your classes is `#import`'ing something *twice* that it shouldn't. If you look carefully, `libLinkedInClientLibrary` and `libOAuth` both symbolicate the same method '_EstimateBas64EncodedDataSize'. Check your #imports.

Comment: according to Transcript text file .. Base64Transcoder.o is in libLinkedInClientLibrary.a and libOAuth.a.. how I remove from it... I tried to remove the 4 files from MGTwitterEngine (NSData+64.h/m, NSString+UUID.h/m), but it not help