# Linedin-Iphone mgtwitterengine using with source code instead of compiled libraries

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, linkedin-api, mgtwitterengine

I am using Twitter SDk and linkedin sdk for iOS in my Iphone application

TwitterEngine : https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

LinkedInIphone : https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone

But I have facing problem.. as I am discussing [IPhone + Twitter + LinkedIn + Facebook Error : Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259747/)

As when I am using linkedIn iOS SDK and twitter iOS SDK.. we have compiled library...

I want to try it with source files so that we can remove the duplicate files easily, can any boy help me how we use direct source files instead of already complied libraries.

**Amit Battan**

Comment: I done one thing that is ...
I remove the library files of linkedin sdk.. and add the source files of it with oAuth files from twiiter sdk... then it works ok for linkedin
http://i.imgur.com/cXLXU.png .... http://i.imgur.com/ntV9G.png ....

then I integrate all twitter code then project run ok without error but for twitter login interface it shows "PAGE NOT FOUND" ..
http://i.imgur.com/8a1ua.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I done one thing that is ...

I remove the library files of linkedin sdk.. and add the source files of it with oAuth files from twiiter sdk... then it works ok for linkedin

i.imgur.com/cXLXU.png ....

i.imgur.com/ntV9G.png ....

then I integrate all twitter code then project run ok without error but for twitter login interface it shows "PAGE NOT FOUND" ..

i.imgur.com/8a1ua.png

But then Notice that I have given the same key and secret to both linkedin and twitter ..

after changing them it solved....

Comment: I have been trying to do that but unfortunately, its not working for me. So I have end up putting the files with different names and changing the API in the names as well for the Linked In.